# Pagerjs and Knockout data-binding - trigger an input's onchange event?

Tags: c#, knockout.js, pagerjs

Is there any way to trigger an  onchange event when the value is data bound by knockout?

I built/populated a model within a C# controller...  then in the view:

```
    var model = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');

    var viewModel = new catalogDetailViewModel(model);

    // extend your view-model with pager.js specific data
    pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);
    // apply the view-model using KnockoutJS as normal
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    // start pager.js
    pager.start();
```

I bind a textbox (which will be eventually a hidden input):

```
<input type="text" id="shoppingCartStyleCatalogID" data-bind="value:styleCatalogID" onchange="GetItemSizes(this.value)" />
```

But it is not triggering the onchange event...  I can watch the value change in dev tools but nothing gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You could also subscribe to the styleCatalogID observable as follow :

```
viewModel.styleCatalogID.subscribe(GetItemSizes);
```